# How to use arrow keys to select a menu item from an emacs shell buffer

Tags: shell, eshell

It is getting more and more common for clis to have little embedded menus (for example the Ionic cli does this, but so do many others) which you navigate with the arrow keys.

```
Please select the JavaScript framework to use for your new app. To bypass this prompt next time, supply a value for the --type option.

? Framework: (Use arrow keys)
❯ Angular | https://angular.io 
  React   | https://reactjs.org
```

I find that when running these in emacs (in eshell usually but also just regular shell), I cannot select items from the menu as it seems arrow keys are not sent.

What's a reasonable workaround here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of application assumes a terminal emulator, not just a shell.  Run it inside `M-x ansi-term` or if you're feeling adventurous, [vterm](https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm).